# Return PriorityQueue value

Tags: python, priority-queue

In my code, I want to be able to retrieve *both* my value *and* the priority value associated with it as a tuple. Is this possible?

```
q = PriorityQueue()
q.put('hello', 0)
print q # I want this to read as a tuple ('hello', 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass the tuple with priority at index 0 and the data at index 1  to the `put` method. Check https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.PriorityQueue:

`q.put((0, 'hello'))`

Then use `get` for retrieving and it will return the whole tuple:

```
item = q.get()
print(item)  # (0, 'hello')
```

Comment: Works in the console but I'm getting `put() take 3 arguements, 2 given` for some reason in my code

Comment: This may because I'm running 2.7.10 in my terminal and 2.7.6 in my codebase

Comment: It's probably because you write `q.put('hello', 0)` instead of `q.put((0, 'hello'))` (note the tuple passed in my example).

Comment: Nope, both don't work. I got this to work by adding a `True` flag. For some reason, this answer works in my terminal, but in my older codebase, it needs the `True` flag. My codebase **DOESN'T** need the `True` flag if I'm not explicitly adding a tuple. Strange. Thanks !